# Finding out Percentage Value using Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

**I have some tables as:**

```
Table_1:
+------------+--------------+
| Student_ID | Student_Name |
+------------+--------------+
|        000 | Jack         |
|        001 | Ron          |
|        002 | Nick         |
+------------+--------------+

Table_2:
+-----+-------+-------+
| ID  | Total | Score |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 000 |   100 |    80 |
| 001 |   100 |    80 |
| 002 |   100 |    80 |
+-----+-------+-------+

Table_3:
+-----+-------+-------+
| ID  | Total | Score |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 000 |   100 |    60 |
| 001 |   100 |    80 |
| 002 |   100 |    70 |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

**Expected_Output:**

```
ID  percent
000 70
001 80
002 75
```

I have created a hive table before. Now, I want to come up with a single HiveQL so that, I can get the expected output from these above 3 tables. 
What I am thinking to do is, in my query I will:

1. use the Left outer join using ID
2. find the sum of "Total" and "Score" for each ID
3. divide sum of "Score" by sum of "Total" to get percentage.

I came up with this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE expected_output 
SELECT t1.Student_ID AS ID, (100*t4.SUM1/t4.SUM2) AS percent
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
SELECT (ISNULL(Total,0) + ISNULL(Total,0)) AS ‘SUM2’, (ISNULL(Score,0) + ISNULL(Score,0)) AS ‘SUM1’
FROM t4
)ON (t1.Student_ID=t2.ID) JOIN Table_3 t3 ON (t3.ID=t2.ID);
```

And, I am stuck at this point. Not sure how to reach to the result.
Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple `join`. Assuming you have one row per id in each of tables t2 and t3, you can do

```
SELECT t2.Student_ID AS ID, 100.0*(t2.score+t3.score)/(t2.total+t3.total) AS percent
FROM Table_2 t2
JOIN Table_3 t3 ON t3.ID=t2.ID
```

Comment: Thank you! If I have any null value in any column, can I replace it by 0 in this method?

Comment: sure you can..use `isnull` as you did in your query.